# GETH - Pending Transactions Performance

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm currently making use of my own GETH node to get pending transactions and process them as follows:

```
this.web3.eth
            .subscribe('pendingTransactions', function (error, result) {})
            .on('data', function (transactionHash) {
                //Do stuff
             }
```

My GETH node startup script looks as follows:

```
--syncmode "fast" --maxpeers 200 --cache 16384 --ws --ws.origins "*"ws.origins "*"
```

The machine has 32GB ram, SSD and 8 CPU cores.

Now my problem is as follows:

- Pending transactions are expected to come through at a steady pace
- It's unfortunately not the case
- For some reason the GETH node server CPU goes to 60 - 100% at random times for a few seconds and that blocks the pending transactions in some way as the pending transactions stop to come through.

Any idea what this is and how I can stop these "freezes" from happening?